# Is there a function with similar performance to `memchr` that can match each char with a bit-mask instead of for exact equality?

Tags: c++, c, utf-8

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is to search for occurrences of the bit patterns (`110xxxxx`, `1110xxxx`, `11110xxx`) which indicate the start of multi-bytes characters in UTF-8.

I was hoping to find something similar in speed to `memchr()` but haven't managed to find anything. I can't write the assembly myself because it has to be portable.

Comment: The short answer is: no there isn't.

Comment: Try `std::find_if`.

Comment: What behavior would you want if the input contained non-UTF-8 bytes? You can optimize finding valid start bytes, but that might not be very useful if it means you silently ignore data corruption.

Comment: Have you tried SIMD operations that do exactly this (and have extremely fast performance)? If not, I'll post an answer with more details on how to use that solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to locate the first UTF-8 sequence start byte. The test is:

```
(c >= 0xC0 && c <= 0xF7)
```

This can be done quite effectively with a single test per byte:

```
void *memfind_start_byte(const void *p, size_t len) {
    unsigned char *s = (unsigned char *)p;
    while (len-- > 0) {
        if ((unsigned char)(*s++ - 0xC0) <= 0xF7 - 0xC0)
            return (void *)(s - 1);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

This loop can be unrolled more or less automatically by optimizing compilers.

You can use a bitwise trick to check multiple bytes at a time, as there is for `strlen()`: after aligning the source pointer, you can check 8 bytes at a time with this:

```
if (*(uint64_t*)p & 0x8080808080808080) {
    /* one byte might match: write 8 tests */
}
```

Here is an untested attempt:

```
void *memfind_start_byte(const void *p, size_t len) {
    unsigned char *s = (unsigned char *)p;
    while (((uintptr_t)s & 7) && len-- > 0) {
        if ((unsigned char)(*s++ - 0xC0) <= 0xF7 - 0xC0)
            return (void *)(s - 1);
    }
    for (; len >= 8; len -= 8, s += 8) {
        if (*(uint64_t *)s & 0x8080808080808080) {
            if ((unsigned char)(s[0] - 0xC0) <= 0xF7 - 0xC0) return (void *)(s + 0);
            if ((unsigned char)(s[1] - 0xC0) <= 0xF7 - 0xC0) return (void *)(s + 1);
            if ((unsigned char)(s[2] - 0xC0) <= 0xF7 - 0xC0) return (void *)(s + 2);
            if ((unsigned char)(s[3] - 0xC0) <= 0xF7 - 0xC0) return (void *)(s + 3);
            if ((unsigned char)(s[4] - 0xC0) <= 0xF7 - 0xC0) return (void *)(s + 4);
            if ((unsigned char)(s[5] - 0xC0) <= 0xF7 - 0xC0) return (void *)(s + 5);
            if ((unsigned char)(s[6] - 0xC0) <= 0xF7 - 0xC0) return (void *)(s + 6);
            if ((unsigned char)(s[7] - 0xC0) <= 0xF7 - 0xC0) return (void *)(s + 7);
        }
    }
    while (len-- > 0) {
        if ((unsigned char)(*s++ - 0xC0) <= 0xF7 - 0xC0)
            return (void *)(s - 1);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely better than my naive attempts. I will try to benchmark this later.